# Ubuntu autoinstall, cant get past welcome screen

Tags: 20.04, autoinstall

cant get it past the welcome screen using auto,this is the welcome screen that asks for keyboard typing, timezome, wifi, privacy, user creation.. if i reboot at this screen without entering anything it goes to the login screen but i want to get around getting to this screen to begin with

timezone, user creation also created by the preseed conf

my grub is already set as per below

```
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed auto=true priority=critical debian-installer/locale=en_US debian-installer/language-en keyboard-configuration/layoutcode=us ubiquity/reboot=casper languagechooser/language-name=English countrychooser/shortlist=US localechooser/supported-locales=en_US.UTF-8 boot=casper automatic-ubiquity autoinstall quiet splash noprompt noshell ---
```

and in my config, ive already set new items such as;

```
ubiquity        languagechooser/language-name   select  English
ubiquity        countrychooser/shortlist        select  US
ubiquity        countrychooser/countryname      select  US
ubiquity        countrychooser/country-name      string US
debconf         debconf/language        string  en
ubiquity        console-keymaps-at/keymap       select  us
ubiquity        tzconfig/gmt    boolean false
ubiquity        time/zone       select  Australia/Sydney
ubiquity        debian-installer/country        string US
ubiquity        debian-installer/language       string en
ubiquity        debian-installer/locale select  en_US
console-setup   console-setup/layoutcode        select  us
console-setup   console-setup/modelcode select  pc105
console-setup   console-setup/layout    select  US
console-setup   console-setup/variant   select  US
d-i console-setup/ask_detect boolean false
d-i debian-installer/framebuffer boolean false
d-i keyboard-configuration/xkb-keymap select us
```

is there a way to verify the above settings to ensure they are entered correctly without guessing running a build thats taking several hours each time?

Comment: Please be clear with details. Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is available with different ISOs which select which installer you're using; with two different *autoseed* configuration rules, but you've not said which you're actually using (*does your config match the installer you've opted to use? ie. preseed vs autoinstall*). Details in the title should also be in the question text (some browser setups don't show title when reading page and your question "*cant get it past the welcome screen*" gives no context!)

Comment: @guiverc where can i find more documentation about the options, i added automatic-ubiquity after, but didnt seem to make any difference anyway

Comment: `ubiquity` is the older (*deprecated*) Ubuntu Desktop installer, it's preseed was based on *d-i* or the Debian installer, which was also used by Ubuntu Server in the past. Ubuntu Server switched to `subiquity` some time ago, with Ubuntu 23.04 the first Desktop release using the newer `ubuntu-desktop-installer` (previously *canary* installer) which uses `subiquity` at its core. I'll provide https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall which is Server doco & covers the `subiquity` & thus `ubuntu-desktop-installer`, but most Desktop ISOs still use the older format (inc. *legacy* 23.04)